# how to get file names exisiting in a folder and put it in Jtable

Tags: java, jtable

When I run my programme, I get only the first file name repeated as many times as files exist in the chosen folder (as rows).
For example, if I have three files in a folder, file1, file2 and file 3, after running the programme the Jtable will return:

```
file1
file1
file1
```

Here is my code:

```
File files = new File(directory);
File[] listOfFiles = files.listFiles(); 

DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
dtm.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
dtm.fireTableDataChanged();
Vector dataRows = new Vector();
dtm.addColumn("Nom");
for (File  fichier : listOfFiles) 
{
  if (fichier.isFile()) 
  {
    fileNames = fichier.getName();
    if (fileNames.endsWith(".txt") || fileNames.endsWith(".TXT"))
    {
      dataRows.add(fileNames);
      dtm.addRow(dataRows);
    }
  }
}
TblFile.setModel(dtm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new instance of the `Vector` `dataRows` for each file, otherwise you're just adding the names as columns

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with swing, but try reinitializing the vector for each row, otherwise you are just adding on to the same vector object, which will always have the first entry as your first file

```
   for (File  fichier : listOfFiles) 
   {

     if (fichier.isFile()) 
     {  

       fileNames = fichier.getName();
       if (fileNames.endsWith(".txt") || fileNames.endsWith(".TXT"))

       {
         Vector dataRows = new Vector();
         dataRows.add(fileNames);
         dtm.addRow(dataRows);


       }
    }

  }
 TblFile.setModel(dtm);
```